# Shortcut to move one image to a different folder?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I have tons of pics. I would like to create a keyboard shortcut with numbers

For example:

With the image selected press Ctrl+1 to move to a different folder

Category Pets Folder C:/Pets Shortcut Ctrl+1

Category Guns Folder C:/Guns Shortcut Ctrl+2

Etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an application that can do this out of the box. you'll need to install `autohotkey`  and do a little bit programming, just a little bit, example:

```
;comment: use CTRL+1 to move selected files to c:\Pets
^1::
Send,^c
Loop, parse, clipboard, `n, `r
{
FileMove,%A_LoopField%,c:\Pets
}
Return

;comment: use CTRL+2 to move selected files to c:\Guns 
^2::
Send,^c
Loop, parse, clipboard, `n, `r
{
FileMove,%A_LoopField%,c:\Guns
}
Return
```

save this code to filename.ahk and execute it(given you've install `autohotkey`) , and you are good to go.